# How to run an OU process with correlation in the wiener process

Tags: matlab, process, correlation

I run in the following problem. I have two vectors with daily intercept estimates, I assume that the behavior of intercepts both follows a OU-process, separately. However, there is a strong correlation between the intercepts, so in order to process both OU-processes I want to correlate the wiener processes of both OU-processes. The question: I do not know how I can implement the correlation coefficient in my code, may be somebody can help me out: I am running the following code:

```
 %model  intercept   
 x = inter_w;
 dx = diff(x);
 dt = 1/252; % Time in years (252 observations per year)
 dxdt = dx/dt;
 x(end) = []; % To ensure the number of elements in x and dxdt match

 % Fit a linear trend to estimate mean reversion parameters 
 coeff = polyfit(x, dxdt, 1); 
 res = dxdt - polyval(coeff, x);
 revRate   = -coeff(1)
 meanLevel = coeff(2)/revRate
 vol       = std(res) * sqrt(dt)

 OUmodel = hwv(revRate, meanLevel, vol,  'StartState', inter_w(507,1), 'Correlation', corr)
```

the second OU-process

```
 y = inter_s; dy = diff(y); 
 dt = 1/252; % Time in years (252 observations per year) 
 dydt = dy/dt; y(end) = []; % To ensure the number of elements in x and dxdt match

 % Fit a linear trend to estimate mean reversion parameters 
 coeffy = polyfit(y, dydt, 1); 
 resy = dydt - polyval(coeffy, y);
 revRatey   = -coeffy(1)
 meanLevely = coeffy(2)/revRatey
 voly       = std(resy) * sqrt(dt)

 y = inter_s;
dy = diff(y);
dt = 1/252; % Time in years (252 observations per year)
dydt = dy/dt;
y(end) = []; % To ensure the number of elements in x and dxdt match

% Fit a linear trend to estimate mean reversion parameters
coeffy = polyfit(y, dydt, 1);
resy = dydt - polyval(coeffy, y);

revRatey   = -coeffy(1)
meanLevely = coeffy(2)/revRatey
voly       = std(resy) * sqrt(dt)

OUmodely = hwv(revRatey, meanLevely, voly, 'StartState', inter_s(507,1), 'Correlation', corr)
```

If I understand the explanation my wiener process is now correlated with a correlation coefficient "corr". However, if I simulate  a 1000 inter_w and a 1000 inter_s the correlation between those processes are not even close to "corr".. I made a mistake somewhere, but do not know where.. Thank you for you response.

Comment: sorry for the repost, but I see I made a mistake

Comment: I already found this:

Comment: "Correlation between Gaussian random variates drawn to generate the Brownian motion vector (Wiener processes). Specify Correlation as an NBROWNS-by-NBROWNS positive semidefinite matrix, or as a deterministic function C(t) that accepts the current time t and returns an NBROWNS-by-NBROWNS positive semidefinite correlation matrix.
A Correlation matrix represents a static condition.
As a deterministic function of time, Correlation allows you to specify a dynamic correlation structure.